# Adding dynamic meta tags to a React static site, created using StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

We're doing a website using [StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin](https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin), is a website plugin that render the site locally and then we can upload it to S3.

Our code looks basically like [this github project](https://github.com/dvidsilva/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin-example)

We're using [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to manage our head, meta info and all that, and is working great in the browser, but not when running the prod build.

In the entry.js I have the following. Missing a way to add the generated strings by Helmet into the resulting html, or if there's a better manager than helmet that will work better with the plugin we're using.

```
export default function render(locals, callback) {
    const element = React.createElement(Root, props);
    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element);
    callback(null, `<!DOCTYPE html>${html}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but "don't blog about html":

```
const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element);
html.replace("</head>", helmet+"</head>");
callback(null, `<!DOCTYPE html>${html}`);
```